# Do I need soffit vents if I have an attic fan?

Tags: roofing, venting

We are in the process of replacing our roof. Our roofs aren’t long enough for Soffit vents and we have loose insulation in the attic. Our roofer is installing a ridge vent at the top but no intake vents given it will moisten the loose insulation on the attic floor. We do have an attic fan, though. Will the ridge vent allow air to flow in when the fan is on, or do they only allow air to flow out?

Comment: Explain your roofs not long enough.  Unless they are less than a few inches overhang, there is space for vents.  Moisten insulation sounds like a snake oil sales pitch.

Comment: it’s an old home without soffits, only hangs an inch. the insulation is loose and not sealed in the attic. I think the concern is that water will get in via bottom vents

Comment: Water only gets in if the person putting them in, does not know what they are doing and probably should not be in that business.

Comment: Vents can all work either direction, so you need to place them and size them for the desired airflow direction. The unobstructed open area of your ridge vent should match the unobstructed open area of the (needed) soffit vents. Every outflow vent needs matching inflow source (vents).

Comment: See https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.2 to determine if the attic fan is even necessary.

Comment: thank you all. what do people typically do for intake if there are no soffits?

Comment: Will depend on type of roof.  vents low on the gable ends(both) or roof vents low on the roof itself.  You have the high vent(ridge) already(or soon).